# Howto design a generic jquery ui dialog view ( backbonejs )

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I have a requirement where i need to have a generic Backbone View that will be enclosed in a jquery UI dialog. This view should provide the following functionalities:

1. Can be called from any other View.
2. The dialog views input fields value should to be passed back to the calling View.
3. Can call another View ( again a jquery dialog ) and hide itself. When a Submit/OK is clicked on the new view the previous dialog will be shown again. ( here too the new dialog will give some information to the calling dialog)

For 1] I am putting an empty div in each view that has to call the dialog. But this is not generic.

For 2] Currently i set some field of the calling view from the dialog view. I am not happy with this implementation, since:
     a] we are accessing another views elements from a diff view and
     b] This becomes complex, when more than one view calls the dialog view. Since i need to have a flag to tell me which view called this dialog view, so i can set its elements value.
Is there a better way to *pass* information from one view to another in such a scenario?

For 3] I am yet to come up with a good design.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is what you're looking for, but here's my hack.  It works for one of my own projects and definitely could be improved.  The "#addQuizDialog" is an empty div in the DOM.  I clone it because I remove it elsewhere in other code.  Adding the div dynamically is also an option, but it created other problems for me that I can't remember at this time.

```
 addQuizDialog: function(){
      console.log("_QuizListView addQuizDialog called")
      var self = this;
      $("#addQuizDialog").clone().load("/templates/addQuizDialog.jade").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Create New Quiz",
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false, 
        buttons: [
          {
            text: "Save",
            click: function() { 
              // create a Quiz model
              var display = $(this).find("form input[name=display]").val();
              var description = $(this).find("form input[name=description]").val();
              var dialog = this;
              // check for existing model by this display name
              $.get('/document/quiz/search',{"display":display},function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                if (data.exists === true){
                  if ($("#addQuizDialog p.ui-state-error").length > 0){
                    // do nothing
                  } else {
                   $("#addQuizDialog p").append("<br><p class='ui-state-error'>A quiz by that name already exists!</p>") 
                  }
                  return false;
                }
                self.collection.create({"display":display,"description":description});
                $(dialog).dialog("close");
              });
            }
          },
          {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          }
        ],
       beforeClose: function(event, ui) { 
          console.log("beforeClose called");
          $(this).remove();
          return true;
          },
      },self).dialog("open");
    },
```